# ASP.NET XML ObjectDataSource Wrapper Class Examples

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, objectdatasource

I want to use XML instead of SQLServer for a simple website.

Are their any good tutorials, code examples, and/or tools available to make a (prefer VB.NET) wrapper class to handle the basic list, insert, edit, and delete (CRUD) code?

The closest one I found was on a Telerik Trainer video/code for their Scheduler component where they used XML to handle the scheduling data in the demo. They created an ObjectDataSource class. Here is a [LINK](http://www.telerik.com/support/teleriktrainer/teleriktrainerpreview/b332i-bb-b332c-a.aspx) to that demo if anyone is interested.

[Reply to Esteban]

it would make deployment easier for clients that use godaddy where the database isn't in the app_data folder. also backing up those websites would be as simple as FTP the entire thing.

i have concerns about possible collisions on saving. especially if I add something as simple as a click counter to say a list of mp3 files visitors to the site can access.

Answer (score 2):

In these days of **SQL Server Express**, I'd say there's really no reason for you not to use a database.

I know this doesn't really answer your question, but I'd hate to see you roll out code that will be a nightmare to maintain and scale.

Maybe you could tell us why you want to use **XML** files instead of a proper database.

Answer (score 0):

It would make deployment easier for clients that use go-daddy where the database isn't in the app_data folder. also backing up those websites would be as simple as FTP the entire thing.

I have concerns about possible collisions on saving. especially if I add something as simple as a click counter to say a list of mp3 files visitors to the site can access.